# Talking about works under submission without breaching anonymity

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, anonymity

I work in a medium/small-sized field within Computer Science. In this field, there are three major conferences. I'm currently submitting my resume/statement to one of these conferences as part of an application. I want to talk about my current works which are under submission to other conferences because they are very relevant to the application. I also want to include where they are being submitted because it adds a lot of value to the quality of work. However, I'm afraid that if I mention what I'm working on + where the works are submitted, that it would be really easy to link me and my group as the authors. This I think could potentially breach the anonymity of our submissions (double blind peer review).

Is this a reasonable concern? Or is this still done?

Comment: `I also want to include where they are being submitted because it adds a lot of value to the quality of work.` No it doesn't. You can submit anything. I personally find it notably weird when I see this.

Comment: @Thomas Well, "submitted to <insert A* conference>" means "my coauthors and I think it's good stuff". Then, you are free to interpret this as you wish (in view of the quality and location of their other publications, and of those of their coauthors).

Comment: I'd be impressed by an undergrad's having two papers in FOCS (meaning actually presented there or at least officially accepted). But 2 other papers submitted to anywhere would not impress me any more than 2 other papers on the arXiv.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni If I see "submitted to X", I'm going to assume you submitted there solely to impress me, rather than because you think it will get in. This should be a separate question if you wish to have more detailed viewpoints.

Comment: @Thomas I find this to be highly unlikely. I have never head of anybody submitting a paper just so they could brag about it being "in submission." It is highly impractical even for this purpose. More often that not, you submit because, as Federico pointed out, you feel like the work has enough merit. Anyway, yes, this seems like good material for another question. As of now, let's focus on the actual anonymity breach question.

Answer (score 1):

The point of blinding authors is to prevent implicit biases from influencing the reviewers' judgements. It's [practically impossible to blind properly](http://blogs.plos.org/absolutely-maybe/2017/10/31/the-fractured-logic-of-blinded-peer-review-in-journals/); reviewers are probably able to deduce your identity if they want to. However, a good reviewer shouldn't want to: they should judge your work by its own merits. Thus, in my opinion you should be able to simply mention the other conferences.

(Also: the value of your work is in the work itself - where it is submitted doesn't *add* anything to that, it merely signals the value you think it has. Not really relevant to this question, but it might help to sharpen your thinking.)