# Can I include paper submitted to ICLR on my CV as a first year master student?

Tags: masters, computer-science, cv

I just started my Master this fall. I am preparing CV for summer internship, preferably to research position in companies like Deepmind (I've know undergrad who got in Deepmind so I want to give it a shot and try my luck).

I want to include the paper title and a short summary in my CV to show the recruiters my research area and I wish to have the opportunity to talk about them in case the recruiters are interested in the topic of the article.

The paper was recently submitted to ICLR for double-blind review. I looked up on this forum and people saying it can be shared in private. My goal is not to have the recruiter read it verbatim so it should be good? Like if they ask me questions and I answer that, does that violate the rule?
Thanks!!

Comment: What does ICLR stand for?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth https://iclr.cc

Comment: Is the paper on arXiv?

Comment: Also related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/105437/68109